# jenkins with groovy postbuild .Not able to execute anything in groovy script field

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to run set of code after the build is completed. I use groovy postbuild plugin(version2.2). I am new to jenkins and groovy. I tried simple println but it is not working. I tried something like this and its also not working. I dont even see error message if i make any syntax or something.
[image: groovy]

and i see this output

[image: console output]

can anyone tell me how do i use groovy postbuild ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your groovy postbuild configuration and syntax look fine to me.

I assume you are experiencing this with a **Build Flow** type job.
I can reproduce this behavior with a configuration similar to yours and I suspect that it is related to the build flow.

One solution that worked for me was to enable the `Flow run needs a workspace` checkbox in the **Flow** section of the job configuration and start a new build.

Comment: While that checkbox is needed to enable execution of the Groovy Postbuild script, the bare `println` method seems unavailable in that context. I had to use `manager.listener.logger.println`